# Objects in the list not being converted to XML

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have an 'Order' class which contains a list of objects of class 'Triplet'.
When I try to get an order object in xml format I get all other data properly except this. Following is the code snippet:

Order.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order {
    private String orderid;
    private String orderStatus;
    private String paidStatus;
    private String address;
    private double total;
    private String emailid;
    private String username;
    private List<Triplet> movies=new ArrayList<>();
    public Order(String orderid, String orderStatus, String paidStatus,      String address, double total, String emailid,
        String username) {
    super();
    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    this.paidStatus = paidStatus;
    this.address = address;
    this.total = total;
    this.emailid = emailid;
    this.username = username;
}

public Order(String orderid, String orderStatus, String paidStatus, String address, double total, String emailid,
        String username, List<Triplet> movies) {
    super();
    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    this.paidStatus = paidStatus;
    this.address = address;
    this.total = total;
    this.emailid = emailid;
    this.username = username;
    this.movies = movies;
}


    public Order() {
    super();
}
 //getters and setters
public String getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}
public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
}
public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}
public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}
public String getPaidStatus() {
    return paidStatus;
}
public void setPaidStatus(String paidStatus) {
    this.paidStatus = paidStatus;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}
public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}
public String getEmailid() {
    return emailid;
}
public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
    this.emailid = emailid;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public List<Triplet> getMovies() {
    return movies;
}
public void setMovies(List<Triplet> movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}
    public Order getObject(){
        Order o=new Order();
        o.setAddress("address1");
        o.setEmailid("email");
        o.setOrderid("orderid");
        o.setOrderStatus("in process");
        o.setPaidStatus("n");
        o.setTotal(250.5);
        o.setUsername("admin");
        movies.add(new Triplet(1L,2,200.0));
        movies.add(new Triplet(2L,3,150.0));
        o.setMovies(movies);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Triplet.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Triplet implements Serializable {

 private long movieid;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;



    public Triplet() {
        super();
    }

    public Triplet(long movieid, int quantity, double price) {
        this.movieid = movieid;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getMovieid() { return movieid; }
    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public double getPrice() { return price; }
}
```

OrderResource.java:

```
@Path("/orders")
public class OrderResource {
OrderService os=new OrderService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/{emailid}")
public Order getOrderByCustomer(@PathParam("emailid") String emailid){
    Order o=new Order();
    return o.getObject();
}
}
```

Output:

```
<order>
<address>address1</address>
<emailid>email</emailid>
<movies/>
<movies/>
<orderStatus>in process</orderStatus>
<orderid>orderid</orderid>
<paidStatus>n</paidStatus>
<total>250.5</total>
<username>admin</username>
</order>
```

What can be done to get proper values in movies?

**Edit**

The problem was that the list of Triplet class object in Order object was not getting converted to XML.

To solve this problem adding an annotation - @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to Triplet class works as mentioned in the EDIT part of the answer given by dsp_user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting any values in <movies> because the Order class has no getter for the movies property/field. Change your Order class to something like

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order {
...
 @XmlElement
private List<Triplet> movies;

public List<Triplet> getMovies(){
  if(movies == null)
     movies = new ArrayList<Triplet>();

  return movies;
}
 ....
   //The setter for  movies isn't necessary because you can add new movies 
   //by calling getMovies().add(new Movie(1L,2,300.0));

}
```

I haven't tried this with your data but I've done something similar in the past so I know it should work.

EDIT: I've now tried your code and it works if you just add one annotation to the Triplet class.

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Triplet  {
 ...
 }
```

I tested with this code (both the commented and uncommented)

```
 final String ORDER_XML = "C:\\test\\Order.xml";

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Order.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    Order o = new Order();

   /* o.setAddress("address1");
    o.setEmailid("email");
    o.setOrderid("orderid");
    o.setOrderStatus("in process");
    o.setPaidStatus("n");
    o.setTotal(250.5);
    o.setUsername("admin");

    o.getMovies().add(new Triplet(1L,2,200.0));
    o.getMovies().add(new Triplet(2L,3,150.0));
    o.getMovies().add(new Triplet(3L,3,400.0));*/
    //o.setMovies(movies);
    m.marshal(o.getObject(), new File(ORDER_XML));
```

The generated XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <address>address1</address>
    <emailid>email</emailid>
    <movies>
        <movieid>1</movieid>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <price>200.0</price>
    </movies>
    <movies>
        <movieid>2</movieid>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <price>150.0</price>
    </movies>
    <orderStatus>in process</orderStatus>
    <orderid>orderid</orderid>
    <paidStatus>n</paidStatus>
    <total>250.5</total>
    <username>admin</username>
</order>
```

Comment: I didn't show any getter setters to not make it bulky. This isn't the entire class. My entire Order class is :

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I'm editing my question to original code. I already have the setters and getters.

Comment: now check the code. This is the original code. Your suggestion is already there.

Comment: just adding @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change `movies.add` to `o.movies.add`. You are modifying the `list` of `movies` that is held by `this` reference whereas in `getObject` method you are returning a different instance all together.

Comment: Tried that still same output. And i also tried printing the returned object in the console, there i am getting all the values. The problem is in getting the values in XML format.